# Twitter Bootstrap Nested Grid Drop Column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can this be done in Twitter Bootstrap using the same markup by just manipulating the row/column classes?  I have laid it out with separate markup for the different sizes.  Ideally I'd like one markup and have it collapse appropriately for the smaller screens.

**Large View**

```
----------------- ------------------------------------------
|               | |                                        |
|               | |               Two                      |
|     One       | ------------------------------------------
|               | |                                        |
|               | |               Three                    |
----------------- ------------------------------------------
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">One</div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">Two</div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">Three</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Medium/Small Views**

```
----------------- ------------------------------------------
|               | |                                        |
|     One       | |               Two                      |
|               | |                                        |
----------------- ------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                          |
|                     Three                                |
|                                                          |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">One</div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">Three</div>
    </div>
```

For xs view, I will just stack them all on top of each other.

Comment: After much googling and thinking, I feel this can not be done. For better or worse, I duplicated "Three" and used the hidden-* classes to show/hide it in the two places.

Comment: Yes, it's doable. You have to be willing to learn CSS and use custom CSS. GetBootstrap.com all of the show case sites and every theme out there uses custom CSS and plenty of it. Bootstrap doesn't provide a class for every scenario.

Comment: This can be achieved using bootstrap. What about  the height of the divs? Is it fixed?

Answer (score 2):

## Demo for static height divs

This is achieved using pure **Bootstrap**. The css used here is just for the sake of demo(except the `@media` ).
**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 a"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 b"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 c"></div>
```

**Demo CSS:**

```
.a{ height:200px;background:red; }
@media (max-width:992px){ .a{ height:100px; } }
.b,.c{ height:100px; }
.b{ background:green; }
.c{ background:purple; }
```

---

## Demo for dynamic height divs

Used **jQuery**

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
        var a = $("#a").height();
        $("#b").height(a+'px');
     }
    if ((window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)').matches) || (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) ) {
        $("#b").css('height','auto');
    }

});
```

Comment: If all the heights are known, you can do this, but if the height of `.a` is greater than `.b` the 992 min-width, the content on .b gets pushed down as it's being floated left and not right, that's why, when you have variable heights (and since it's a fluid grid, it is usually variable and explicit heights are not set) you have to float them right at the breakpoint of your choice and clear, as I have done.

Comment: correction, the content of C gets pushed down. I've done this sort of layout before, when you have text inside these divs there's no way to set a height. Fixed heights are not really used in fluid design if you can help it.

Comment: That's cool. window.matchMedia() is only supported in IE10+. https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/. You can use just regular widow width ... `if ($(this).width() >= 768) {`

Comment: Thanks, with all your help I solved this.  I hadn't considered making the widths go greater than 12.  With that simple concept, I got the behavior I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some of the CSS from Bootstrap (just for the col-X-X widths and the padding) and additional CSS. It's better to not repeat content by hiding and showing.

If you want something `.col-sm-4` and `.col-md-4`, using `.col-sm-4` is all that is required. It's the same width from 768px and up.

If you want something full width always, at every viewport size, you don't need the grid at all, so `col-xs-12` is not required and usually, col-md-12 or some other col-X-12 is not required if the class used on the column is in a higher media query.  If there is no column class under the last one used, then it will automatically be full width under that min-width. For example, `.col-md-4` under 992px will be full width so I don't have to writhe `col-sm-12`. I have `col-sm-4` under 768px will be full width and everything from 768px and up will be 1/4 of 12, so I don't have to write col-xs-12.

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/huxofe

**CSS**

```
custom-grid .content-box {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .custom-grid .col-sm-4 {
        clear: right
    }

    .custom-grid .box-3 {
        clear: both
    }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) { 
    .custom-grid .col-lg-4 {
        clear: right
    }

    .custom-grid .col-lg-8 {
        float: right
    }

    .custom-grid .box-3 {
        clear: none
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row custom-grid">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 content-box box-1">
         <h3>Content Box 1</h3>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-box box-2 col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
         <h3>Content Box 2</h3>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-box box-3 col-lg-8">
         <h3>Content Box 3</h3>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Christina: Should the code(CSS) be this big? Please see my answer and feel free to correct me.. :)