# Combining columns in bootstrap for smaller devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 divs inside one div horizontally aligned.

|    1     | 2 | 3 |

In smaller devices, I want 3 to move to under 1 and look like this:

| 1 | 2 |

| 3 | 2 |

I can do that creating different layouts maybe, but is there anyway to do in bootstrap using grids?

EDIT

Here is a demonstration of what I want to achieve. In desktop, I want it to look like this:
[image]

In Mobile:

[image]

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options goes over how grids work for different devices

Comment: Do you literally mean that you want `2` twice?

Comment: if you want to repeat repeat `2nd col` than simply you need replicate the `2nd col` and just show on small devices.

Comment: I actually meant that 2nd column will be size of 1 and 3 together. In regular mode I have 3 horizontal columns, in mobile I want 1 and 3 vertical and 2 next to combination of 1 and 3

Comment: I added pictures that explains better what I want

Comment: See this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681130/twitter-bootstrap-nested-grid-drop-column/27683441#27683441)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Demo

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4" style="height:100px;background:red;">A</div>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 float" style="height:100px;background:blue">B</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4" style="height:100px;background:green">C</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) 
  { 
    .float
    {
      float:right!important;
      height:200px!important;
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it via `col-sm-push` and `col-sm-pull` similar post;

**[Column order manipulation using col-lg-push and col-lg-pull in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap)**

Also check a much detail post [here](http://www.schmalz.io/2014/10/08/Column-Ordering-in-Bootstrap/).

Comment: I already read the bootstrap documentation. What you posted is about the order of columns in vertical line. My question is nesting column 1 and 3 and showing 2nd column next to them.

Comment: I added pictures that shows what I want, please check the question

Comment: @GokhanArik Okay. I will improve answer later. You asked previously different. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the 3rd box to be directly below the 1st box while the 2nd box is higher than the 1st box. This can only be achieved in Bootstrap by duplicating the contents of the 3rd box and hiding/showing it based on the grid size (e.g. `sm`). Pushing or pulling columns, using e.g. `col-sm-push-4`, won't help as they'll never make a column wrap to the next line.

As Bootstrap is a mobile first framework, the first step is to create the small layout. In order to get the 3rd box directly below the 1st box we'll need to use [column nesting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting). The idea is to put the 1st and 3rd box in an inner grid inside the left column of the outer grid, while the 2nd box will be put in right column of the outer grid. Notice that the inner grid needs a `.row` to offset the padding of its parents `col-xs-6`, and that the columns inside the inner grid count up to 12. Some people think it needs to count up to 6 as they exist inside a `col-xs-6`, but that isn't the case.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box box--one">One</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box box--three">Three</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="box box--two">Two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The small layout now looks good. To get the other layout (I've assumed `md` as its breakpoint) change both `col-xs-6` to `col-xs-6 col-md-4` and add a 3rd column to the outer grid containing the 3rd box.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box box--three">Three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It now looks completely broken, the 3rd box is shown twice and one of them is overlapping the 1st and 2nd box on screens smaller than `md`. We can fix this by [hiding the columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) containing the 3rd box for specific grid sizes. To hide the 3rd box inside the inner grid for larger screens change `<div class="col-sm-12">` into `<div class="col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">`. And to hide the 3rd outer column for smaller screens change `<div class="col-md-4">` into `<div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">`

See the entire example code below:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #c66;
  background-color: #f99;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box--one,
.box--three {
  height: 100px;
}
.box--two {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box box--one">One</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
          <div class="box box--three">Three</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="box box--two">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      <div class="box box--three">Three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PS** If you don't like duplicating the 3rd box, as perhaps there's a lot of content inside, you can also use JavaScript to move the box into it's proper column when a breakpoint change occurs. I've made some jQuery plugin prototype that should be able to do this, see https://github.com/ckuijjer/jquery-breakpointspy

**PS** I just saw your updated question: if the boxes have a fixed height, simply add a class to the 3rd box of the large layout that gets a fixed height. If they don't have a fixed height, create some JavaScript that set the height to be equal and attach it to the resize event. A completely different solution would be to look into flexbox.