# Forcing an irregular Bootstrap column / row wrapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a typical grid layout as seen attached:

[image]

I have 2 rows - one with the widget / header columns and another with the sidebar and content.  I did this to keep the widget and header height the same and responsive WITHOUT specifying the height via CSS.

The issue is when it wraps for mobile I want the header and content to stay together at the bottom.  I can do a single row with two columns then nest two rows in each but then I am back to specifying the height of the first rows of each nested grid.

I can make that work but it just seems to me that perhaps there is a more elegant solution which escapes me at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

## DEMO


Instead of putting `widget-header` & `sidebar-content` pairs in **2 separate rows** & using `pull  & push`to adjust the grid, you can easily put `widget-sidebar` in one column & `header-content` in another to solve the problem.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6 main">
 <div class="col-sm-12 a">Widget</div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 a">sidebar</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 main">
 <div class="col-sm-12 a">header</div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 a">content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.a{ /*for demo only*/
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid red;
}
.main{
    padding:0px; /*for no padding between 2 columns in small devices*/
}
```

Comment: That is a cleaner solution if I go the route of having to manually declare the height of widget and header but still doesn't answer my question.  It very well may not be possible either.

Comment: @Jasper502: Could you post your code? or a fiddle? In the pic you posted everything were of same height..thats why i gave a static height in the css..

Comment: I will see what I can get uploaded.  For now I do want the first 'row' (widget & header) the same height.  The idea was that the header is what ever height it needs to be and then the widget is set to fill the height created by the header.  I think now I am making this too hard and should just fix the height and be done with it.

Comment: Before using static height please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681130/twitter-bootstrap-nested-grid-drop-column/27683441#27683441) and please tell me if any help needed... :)